# Browser is converting Danish characters to unicode in HTML textarea

Tags: html, encoding

When I type in or paste Danish characters into HTML `textarea`, they instantly turn to unicode when I inspect it. For example, "Æ, æ
Ø, ø:
Å, å: " turns into "rnrnu00c6, u00e6rnu00d8, u00f8: rnu00c5, u00e5". That's also what gets sent with the request when the form is submitted.

Is there any way to go around it?  Thank you in advance.

Edit: Here is what the text area is, in the inspector in Chrome:

```html
<textarea style="width: 40%; min-height: 80px" placeholder="Your meta description" name="wpo_meta_description" maxlength="160" class="">this's how we test.rnrnu00c6, u00e6rnu00d8, u00f8: rnu00c5, u00e5:</textarea>
```

Also, it's a metabox in WordPress.

Comment: That's not unicode. `Æ, æ Ø, ø: Å, å` is already unicode, and converting to the format you shared is not something that happens by default. Share your code so your issue can be reproduced and people can help you.

Comment: Thanks, @Evert, I stand corrected. It's a simple textarea metabox in Wordpress. But, I've shared it in the original post.

Comment: When I paste this textarea in a blank HTML page, nothing automatically changes and your characters stay intact. There's something going on outside this textarea.

Comment: @Evert , thanks, it's on WordPress, so I will look deeper. Do you have any idea of what could cause something like that? Perhaps some kind of JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, javascript sounds likely!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] using _JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet_ (Ctrl+M) instead of _Code sample_ (Ctrl+K).